# Double for loop to Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following (simplified structure):

```
class Wafer:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.dose_fields = df

class Data:
    def __init__(self, add_zero):
        self.wafers = []
        self.wafers.append(Wafer([1.0, 1.5]))
        self.wafers.append(Wafer([2.0, 2.0]))
        self.wafers.append(Wafer([3.0, 3.5]))
        self.wafers.append(Wafer([4.0, 4.5]))

        if add_zero:
            self.wafers.append(Wafer([5.0, 0.0]))
```

I want to have a function that returns False when there is a zero in one of the `dose_fields` values.

like this:

```
data = Data(True)        
res = True
for wafer in data.wafers:
    for fld in wafer.dose_fields:
        if fld == 0.0:
            res = False
print res

data = Data(False)        
res = True
for wafer in data.wafers:
    for fld in wafer.dose_fields:
        if fld == 0.0:
            res = False
print res
```

This prints False resp. True (what I want).

However, when I try to use list comprehension:

```
data = Data(True)
print [df for df in wafer.dose_fields for wafer in data.wafers]
print res

data = Data(False)
print [df for df in wafer.dose_fields for wafer in data.wafers]
print res
```

I get the result

```
[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5]
True
```

resp

```
[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
True
```

Somehow I get repeats of the last item, while I want the complete list and check afterwards if there is a 0.0 inside.

What should I do to 'repair' the list comprehension statement?

Comment: The loops in LC are not in correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If testing for the presence of `0.0` is really all you want, you should use the `in` operator. Not only is it far more readable, it's much faster. You can then use `any`, too

Instead of:

```
res = True
for wafer in data.wafers:
    for fld in wafer.dose_fields:
        if fld == 0.0:
            res = False
```

do

```
res= not any([0.0 in wafer.dose_fields for wafer in data.wafers])
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested list comprehensions can be a bit confusing. You actually need to write them in the same order as the for loops they replace: so it should be

```
[df for wafer in data.wafers for df in wafer.dose_fields]
```